# Will all implementations be passed automatically ? Who does this?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, nexus, inject

I saw this line in Nexus OSS code ...

```
@Inject
public ReleaseRemoverTask( final ReleaseRemover releaseRemover )
{
    this.releaseRemover = checkNotNull( releaseRemover );
}
```

the above is found in https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-oss/blob/master/components/nexus-core/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/maven/tasks/ReleaseRemoverTask.java

But [ReleaseRemover.java](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-oss/blob/master/components/nexus-core/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/maven/tasks/ReleaseRemover.java) is an interface .

There is no use in interface here , so only the implementation should be passed during runtime ..This only makes sense ..
So I confirmed it by debugging , that the implementation is called .The implementation class was [DefaultReleaseRemover.java](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-oss/blob/master/components/nexus-core/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/maven/tasks/DefaultReleaseRemover.java) .

To support my argument I wrote a plugin for nexus and I wrote an implementation for ReleaseRemover .

Even that was picked up ...

How is this done ?
Internally they are using Google Guice ..

Is Guice doing this job of passing the implementations inside this function ?
Is this the property of frameworks like Google Guice ?

If all implementations are passed like this , can I prevent an implementation from being passed ?

Comment: It seems to be javax.Inject rather than guice's Inject - there has to be a configuration file somewhere that defines which concrete class should be instantiated.

Comment: But even the class that I write in  a plugin a getting called .... They do not know my class name right ? This gives me an impression that they have something to find all the implementations and pass one by one ..

Answer (score 0):

you question is not clear for me. What do you want to achieve? What means `can I prevent an implementation from being passed ?` what you want to pass instead? Null or your implementation?

You are right about that Nexus OSS uses Google Guice as Dependency injection framework. To bind an implementation to some interface you have to create modules where you say something like this:

```
bind(ReleaseRemover.class).to(DefaultReleaseRemover.class);
```

As you see in `DefaultReleaseRemover` there are another injections and they very likely stuck up. So the injected implementation in `DefaultReleaseRemover` contains another injections and so on.

The `DefaultReleaseRemover` is annotated as `@Singleton` which means there is only one instance of `DefaultReleaseRemover` class for whole injector.

Well, you have your interface and implementation and your module with bindings. Now you need to create Guice Injector and use it to create all objects for you.
For Nexus OSS you can find Guice Injection entry point at https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-oss/blob/de6a606372349283f78aeaa498e9a70d4dd967b1/components/nexus-webapp/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/webapp/WebappBootstrap.java line 118

```
Guice.createInjector(your modules...);
```

See, you will provide all modules you want to install to the Guice Injector. Be aware there could be some sub modules installed inside modules. You dont have to explicitly pass it into `createInjector` function. So, if you want to change some Guice bindings it's good start to dig from there.

---

UPDATE:

I don't know the mechanics. But you have to bind your implementation in some `Module.configuration()` as

```
bind(ReleaseRemover.class).annotathedWith(Names.named("custom")).to(MyCustomReleaseRemover.class);
```

The module should be not `PrivateModule`:)

Then you will pass you `CustomReleaseRemover` as

```
@Inject
public ReleaseRemoverTask( final @Named("custom") ReleaseRemover releaseRemover )
```

I would direct you more straight forward, but I have no idea how it works inside Nexus OSS. Maybe somebody could you help with that part.

Comment: ok . to be clear "can I prevent any one particular implementation alone from being passed . for example only pass the implementation that I have inside my plugin and not the DefaultReleaseRemover which is also an implementation but which is inside core nexus ."

Comment: Look inside the default Nexus plugins some of them contains Guice modules. So, you can find out how works Guice for plugins.